# Indy IMAP remove mail attachment from server

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

I want to remove attachments (files) from mails on the (exchange) server.

I currently use IMAP to access the accounts and mailboxes.

How do I remove the attachments on the server side without removing the message?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible with IMAP.  The only option is to download the desired message in full, alter it as needed, delete the original from the server, and then upload the modified copy.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for the answer... I tried deleting the email message, but (because of Imap?) the message doesn't get deleted... Should i use another protocol to achieve what i want?

Comment: @Max is right. When a message a "deleted" in IMAP, it is merely marked with a flag, it is not actually deleted from the server until a separate purge operation is performed. That allows "deleted" messages to be undeleted prior to the purge.